# mysql left join table one to table two by id where table two row newest date and

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, table one

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
| id | pixel                                           | date       |
+----+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
|  2 | 7FB30~8BBEA~2B1FB~D5C54~205BD~05A28~9FAB6~F8D2A | 1417334510 |
|  3 | 7FB30~8BBEA~2B1FB~D5C54~205BD~05A28~9FAB6~F8D2A | 1417358993 |
|  4 | 7FB30~8BBEA~2B1FB~D5C54~205BD~05A28~9FAB6~F8D2A | 1417443262 |
+----+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Table two

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+
| id | lead_id | status | date       |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
| 11 |       3 |      2 | 1417359373 |
| 10 |       2 |      2 | 1417357705 |
| 12 |       2 |      4 | 1417422929 |
| 13 |       4 |      2 | 1417443292 |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
```

I want to join table one to two on one.id to two.lead_id and newest date
and then select it if 2.status equals x

so result would look like this

```
+--------+--------+-------------+------------+-----------+------------+
| one.id | two.id | two.lead_id | two.status | one.pixel | two.date   |
+--------+--------+-------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|   3    |    11  |     3       |       2    | 7FB30...  | 1417359373 |
|   2    |    12  |     2       |       4    | 7FB30...  | 1417422929 |
|   4    |    13  |     4       |       2    | 7FB30...  | 1417443292 |
+--------+--------+-------------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `Select if 2.status equals x`?  What is `x`?

Comment: This question is asked several times a day on SO (and elsewhere). Quite frequently, it's correctly answered too.

Comment: You want the query or how it is done using php? If you need information for mysqli I suggest you see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: none of the answers actually helped me, I tried this time to provide as much info as possibale

Comment: I note that status is in table 2, not table 1.

Comment: I would refer to you the advice I provided previously.

Comment: Your right, will edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "2.status equal x" has to do with the question or the results.  It looks like you want the first record from table 2 on or after table 1.

The idea is to use a correlated subquery to get the id of the row in table2 for each row in table1.  Then join in the rest of the fields:

```
select t.id as one_id, t.two_id, t2.lead_id, t2.status, t.pixel, t2.date
from (select t1.*,
             (select t2.id
              from table2 t2
              where t2.date >= t1.date
              order by date
              limit 1
             ) as two_id
      from table1 t1
     ) t join
     table2 t2
     on t.two_id = t2.id;
```

Comment: if I add status = 2, it will return only if the joind status equals 2

Comment: If you add `where status = 2` to the outer query, it will only return rows where the resulting status is `2`.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 't1.pixel' in 'field list'